# I am trying to deploy a Windows 7 install.wim file with dism, but it says that the apply-image option is unknown. Why?

Tags: dism, windows-pe

I am trying to deploy a Windows 7 install.wim file, but it fails because it says that the apply-image option is unknown.
I am in a Windows 10 22H2 PE and I have tried different ISOs, but it keeps failing with the same error.

```
Error: 87
```

The apply-image option is unknown.

For more information, refer to the help by running DISM.exe /?.

The DISM log file can be found at `X:\windows\Logs\DISM\DISM.log`

Log:

> [image: Log]

Image of error:

> [image: Image of error]

Comment: @John I do not think that is the case, due to it failing to even find the apply-image option.

Comment: I have edited your question, but please avoid posting screenshots of text. Like the log screenshot: Just copy the contents of the log and format it as code. Easier to read and parse as well as makes the text searchable.

Comment: probably a dism versioning mismatch see for example ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/installing-updates-features-roles/dism-error-87-apply-windows-10-image )

Comment: please post text, not pictures of text ... https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @jsotola that's a cool site. Possibly more friendly than the old lmgtfy, lol.

Answer (score 0):

1. The **error** in the log shows "**appydir** C:". That typo does **not** show in the CMD. This appears to be two different attempts.
2. Not sure the *ApplyDir* can be other than root, e.g. C:
3. Why would one want to do this? Historical research? Use a VM, instead.
4. Why tag this *windows-pe*, when you're trying to deploy Win7?

See [usage of DISM](https://ss64.com/nt/dism.html#apply-image).